# Firefox Browser fail to cache swf files

Tags: firefox, caching

We are using Latest version of Firefox for accessing our website. Our website was developed with 4 to 5 swf files, js and amf. 
We observed that swf files are not being cached in firfox browser. 
But in the case of Google Chrome and Internet Explorer all the swf files are being cached.
I would like to know, Any one of you has faced the issue same as mine. If so, Kindly help me.